# After unlink all packages it again following modules are linked manually while react-native upgrade

Tags: react-native

I have updated react-native version to latest.

So I have unlink all manually linked packages. But If i run react-native run-ios after pod install it shows the list of packages again to unlink.

error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually

When pod install it shows the below error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "react-native-webview":
  In Podfile:
    react-native-webview (from `../node_modules/react-native-webview`)

Specs satisfying the `react-native-webview (from `../node_modules/react-native-webview`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: What version of react-native-webview are you using?

Comment: The error states: "dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target". Have you tried incrementing your deployment target and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: After adding the plaform ios is 9.0 it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the platform ios to 9.0 in podfile. It worked for me